# Why can't type theory be applied on personality types?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, types

Given that type theory is a system for describing mathematics, and given that "Math can be applied everywhere", why is it that type theory can't seem to be applied to personality type theory? I've been thinking about this since about I started studying type theory. I'm thinking that one abstraction will be: a jolly man can act as a catalyst on a social environment and then cause the environment to be jolly as well. But I'm thinking as well about the case when a man "wearing a hat" can act as a catalyst on a social environment and then cause the environment to be "wearing a hat" as well. An environment "wearing a hat" doesn't sound good, does it? Well, my main question has a tendency to be flawed, but I would really like to have sincere answers. It would really help if the answers would focus on type theory.

Comment: [This was also posted to math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1522162/264). Please note that [crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068). If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts.

Comment: Also, you haven't addressed the main problem with your question, which is that it is predicated on a meaningless coincidence of terminology as opposed to any substance.

Comment: There is 'Set Theory' and 'he set his dog on the man' has two uses if the word 'set'; they have nothing in common - similarly with the way you are using the word 'type': see above comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an erroneous interpretation of the meaning of "type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only equivocating on two very very different usage of the same word.

In mathematics, "[type](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/)" is a *syntactical* or *ontological* category, while in psychology is a descriptive term that can have a "specific" meaning in the context of a [typology theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_Types) of human personalities.

---

Your example regarding :

> a jolly man "wearing a hat" that act as a catalyst on a social environment and then cause the environment to be "wearing a hat" as well

is a reasonable example of *syntactical* type theory : stretching it a little bit, we can say that the phrase "a social environment is wearing a hat" is a case of [category mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake), because it is not "grammatically correct" to predicate "waring a hat" of "objects" like social environments.